# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.scribe.builder.ServiceBuilder

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, oauth-2.0, scribe

I'm working on simple app, which will connect with Google+ (or Facebook, or Twitter). I am using Scribe library, but I have problem with that. I get the ClassNotFoudException and I don't know why.

My Stack Trace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/scribe/builder/ServiceBuilder
    facebookConnection.servlets.GooglePlus.doGet(GooglePlus.java:38)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.scribe.builder.ServiceBuilder
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    facebookConnection.servlets.GooglePlus.doGet(GooglePlus.java:38)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

Anyone have idea how to solve that?

Comment: I assume you're deploying a WAR file to Tomcat, thus you should check the process of creation of this file. Do you build it with Maven?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following jar files in your project libraries.

> **org/scribe/builder/ServiceBuilder**

you can find above jar file from below url.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/scribe/scribe-1.2.1.jar.zip

Comment: I added it earlier, but I had too add this .jar file to "lib" directory in tomcat too. So problem solved.